# Windows Azure and FileZilla FTP

Tags: macos, azure, ftp, filezilla

I get this problem, when trying to connect to Windows Azure hosted server from my Mac OSX Filezilla FTP Client:

> 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 530 User cannot log in
>
> Error: Critical error
> Error: Could not connect to server

This only started happening as of October 29, 2013. Prior to that, I would get a "Critical error" every now and again, but was always easy to refresh and upload without haste.

I tried CyberDuck and it told me to contact service provider, but has anyone found a solution to this?

We use Windows Azure to host our site, and I run Mac OSX. Surely, this would have always been a problem before and not have just sprung up recently for this reason alone (Windows vs Mac) right?!

Answer (score 2):

Please see: Servicedashboard Windows Azure at http://www.windowsazure.com/nl-nl/support/service-dashboard/

> **30 Oct 2013 7:00 PM UTC**
>   We are aware of an issue being reported regarding Windows Azure Web Sites FTP data access. We are responding to this issue with the highest level of priority. Further updates will be published to keep you apprised of the impact. We apologize for any inconvenience this causes our customers.
>
> **Last update:**
>   We are narrowing in on the issue with full engineering engagement. Web Site customers are advised to publish content using Web Deploy or Git which are fully functional. For details on using these methods, visit Azure.com and search for "Websites with Webmatrix" or "Publishing with Git". We apologize for any inconvenience this causes our customers and will provide an update at 2pm UTC.

Comment: We apologize for any inconvenience this causes customers using FTP to publish content to Web Sites. Web Site customers are advised to use Web Deploy or Git which are fully functional. For details visit Azure.com and search for "Websites with Webmatrix" or "Publishing with Git". Engineering is fully focused on mitigation options. We will provide an update by 8pm UTC.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I keep receiving 550 errors.

Comment: You can check the service dashboard at  http://www.windowsazure.com/nl-nl/support/service-dashboard/

Answer (score 1):

You can find more details on the issue and a possible workaround here  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b2853874-160f-4156-bd0a-0247cac04831/cannot-connect-to-azure-websites-ftp-server?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview