# Trying to access FTP with deployment credentials: 530 User cannot log in

Tags: azure, ftp

I am trying to set up a FTP access to a website which is hosted on Azure:

From what I understand, there are two options: You can choose Username and Password in the management console when resetting your deployment credentials. Or you download the publishing profile and use the credentials which are shown in the FTP section of the XML.

However, none of the two seem to work for me. I keep getting the response:

> 530 User cannot log in.

The ftp server seems to be in place, just the credentials are wrong, obviously. I am 100% sure that I have no typos going on.

What am I missing here? Is there anything I need to configure prior to using FTP with the credentials provided by Azure?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19695178/468244)?

Comment: Nope, I haven't, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably that:

[image]

And more here:

[MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b2853874-160f-4156-bd0a-0247cac04831/cannot-connect-to-azure-websites-ftp-server?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to the Windows Azure Service Dashboard:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

> **30 Oct 2013**
>   We are aware of an issue being reported regarding Windows Azure Web Sites FTP data access. We are responding to this issue with the highest level of priority. Further updates will be published to keep you apprised of the impact. We apologize for any inconvenience this causes our customers.
>
> **Last update: 31 Oct 2013  6:46 AM UTC**
> We are narrowing in on the issue with full engineering engagement. Web Site customers are advised to publish content using Web Deploy or Git which are fully functional. For details on using these methods, visit Azure.com and search for "Websites with Webmatrix" or "Publishing with Git". We apologize for any inconvenience this causes our customers and will provide an update at 2pm UTC.

Comment: We apologize for any inconvenience this causes customers using FTP to publish content to Web Sites. Web Site customers are advised to use Web Deploy or Git which are fully functional. For details visit Azure.com and search for "Websites with Webmatrix" or "Publishing with Git". Engineering is fully focused on mitigation options. We will provide an update by 8pm UTC.

Answer (score 0):

answered Oct 31 '13 at 11:02
Cas Bloem
613

We apologize for any inconvenience this causes customers using FTP to publish content to Web Sites. Web Site customers are advised to use Web Deploy or Git which are fully functional. For details visit Azure.com and search for "Websites with Webmatrix" or "Publishing with Git". Engineering is fully focused on mitigation options. We will provide an update by 8pm UTC.

Answer (score 0):

This is because userId and password you are using is not to be used while connecting.
There is a Get publish profile option in overview.Download it.Open it with notepad or visual studio.There is another userId and Password given.Use that.
[For more info refer this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deployment-credentials)