# Azure web site FTP access / 530 User cannot log in

Tags: ftp, azure

I'm trying to update an Azure Web Site using FTP.  In the past, I was able to do this fine using the credentials from the `.publishsettings` file as has been widely documented.  Today, I can't do that.  Instead, I get a `530 User cannot log in.` - even if I regenerate the publish settings and redownload them, the new ones give me the same issue.

Back in October 2013, there was a set of these, e. g. [Windows Azure and FileZilla FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695178/windows-azure-and-filezilla-ftp) and [Trying to access FTP with deployment credentials: 530 User cannot log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704127/trying-to-access-ftp-with-deployment-credentials-530-user-cannot-log-in), that were a service failure on the Azure side, but the dashboard at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/ shows clean at the moment, so I don't think that's the same issue.

I don't want to create a new FTP/Git deployment user, because according to both the old and new portals, those credentials apply to all sites in the subscription, and I only want credentials for this site specifically.

What else should I be looking at here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a case with Microsoft, and after some back and forth and testing, two things came out:

1. There was a service issue which may or may not have impacted us - it's not clear as it was a partial outage edge case situation.
2. There seems to be a bug in the Windows 10 FTP command-line client as of build 10130 where it doesn't properly handle the credentials.  I haven't done a network capture or anything; using another client seemed to work, so I filed a Feedback item and moved on.

Comment: Would you please share the 'other' client that you used? Thanks.

Comment: It was so very long ago that I don't remember, and I'm sure the bug is long since fixed since I'm been successful with the inbox client since then.  It might have been FTP Explorer, because I was using that some at the time, but I just don't know.

Answer (score 15):

I just tested our account here is an example:

FTP: ftp://waws-prod-bay-014.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot

UserName: fake__dev\$fake__dev

Password: Nope

Port: 21

I think make sure the username has the \ in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am using a \.  I'm using the credentials exactly as given in the publishing file.  This has worked in the past, so I'm not sure what's changed.

Comment: When using node ftp to login to Azure in code ensure that in the javascript string literal for the  Azure username the backslash is escaped. i.e. fake__dev\\$fake__dev.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems lately, while trying to reach `waws-prod-....azurewebsites.net` with my custom deployment credentials, using ftp software like Filezilla. I could reach the server using the publish credentials, but not with my deployment credentials.

For me it turns out that Filezilla sometimes chooses for a HTTP protocol, rather than the FTP. In my case it meant that Filezilla went to `ftp://waws...` when I used the publish credentials, but goes to `http://waws...` when using the deployment credentials.

Simple fix: always use `ftp://` in front of the url.

Comment: This worked for me on filezilla. Need to check cyberduck if its same

Answer (score 1):

When I set user_name\$user_name by git command config git-ftp.user it was not working.

But when I edited .git/config file I noticed that \ was missing.
I replaced it to double \

Whole config file:

```
[git-ftp]
    url = ftp://waws-prod-qwerty.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:21/site/
    password = qwerty
    user = user_name\\$user_name
```

And now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you use the App Credentials. Azure docs mention the following for deploying with user credentials.

> Note
>
> Authenticating to an FTP/FTPS endpoint using user-level credentials
> requirers a username in the following format:

> \

> Since user-level credentials are linked to the user and not a specific
> resource, the username must be in this format to direct the sign-in
> action to the right app endpoint.

[SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply went to this [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-configure-credentials?tabs=portal) and under "Configure user-scope credentials" heading, I opened the Azure portal tab and followed the instructions to get my FTPS credentials. Then, I simply copied and pasted the credentials to my FTP Client (FileZilla) and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This is because userId and password you are using is not to be used while connecting.
There is a Get publish profile option in overview.Download it.Open it with notepad or visual studio.There is another userId and Password given.Use that.
[For more info refer this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deployment-credentials)

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  Please reread the question - I directly referenced the downloaded publishing profile.  The issue was an Azure service issue.